Roman numeral within \cite command latex
I am a beginner in latex and I'm trying to figure out how to include a Roman numeral in the description of the cite command. For example, I want it to look like:

I have this in my preamble,
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

So I did,

\cite[\S\rom{7}.1 Theorem 7.3]{Was12}

But when I do this, the output is what I want but I run into a "missing number treated as zero" error. How do I fix this without having to type "VII" for each such case.
Edit: Added MWE:
My Biblio.bib file contains this
@book{xyz,
  title={abcd},
  author={xyz},
  year={2012},
}

and main tex is:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,
}
\begin{document}
This is \cite[\S\rom{17} Theorem 4]{xyz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Error shown:
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.22 This is \cite[\S\rom{17} Theorem 4]{xyz}^^M
                                                
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


You should provide an example that shows the problem. the code you show is just equivalent  to using \@Roman{7} or indeed VII why use a macro at all here?

Please always make a full but minimal example so we know exactly what you are doing. Why even use a macro here? I'd just use \cite[\S VII.1 Theorem~7.3]{Was12}

For a couple of millennia, Roman numerals have been identified with the letters they resembled (with just a few exceptions). If the article/book you cite has Roman numerals for chapters/sections, just use “VII”: it's actually not a number, but a label, so it should be cited “as is”.

@DavidCarlisle Initially I was expecting to have large Roman numerals I would use, so the code was just a matter of convenience to convert them. I have edited the question to include the exact error.

but surely the work you are citing is using Roman so you see Theorem VII.1 ... in the book and so to cite it you need to back convert the roman to decimal to get tex to convert to Roman again

I updated the answer though

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. I was too naive and tried to manipulate the referencing format: to ensure uniformity in all my references I was trying to have VII.1 (because typically Roman is used for chapters) instead of 7.1 even though my reference uses the latter(which is where I tried to convert to Roman). But as egreg mentions, it would be wrong to do so and I should go by what the book follows and mention them as it is.

You have not shown the error message that you got, nor your input, but it is not due to the code shown, perhaps there is an error in the referenced bib entry.
The code you show is just the definition of the standard \@Roman command which you could use instead, but I would just use VII here; the macro is not gaining you anything.

\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\newcommand\romb{\@Roman}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\cite[\S\rom{7} Theorem 8]{aaa}

\cite[\S\romb{7} Theorem 8]{aaa}

\cite[\S VII Theorem 8]{aaa}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{aaa} one two three
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}



After the edited question the error is an incompatibility with biblatex: you need to use a robust version of the command. So for example defined with \newDocumentCommand or \DeclareRobustCommand
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}


{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\rom{m}{\@Roman{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is \cite[\S\rom{17} Theorem 4]{xyz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

But using \rom{7} is really wrong here you should cite the work as printed, so just use VII directly, this is not a generated number that should be translated to Roman it is a Roman numeral "at source".

+1 for "you should cite the work as printed, so just use VII directly".
